# How to use android:onClick event with Menu XML <item>? It seems to be crashing my program?

Tags: java, android, xml

For some reason my program crashes once android:onClick="confirm" is called in the Menu main1.xml file. Am I incorrectly using the event in the MainActivity.java file?

In MainActivity.java:

Called when the user clicks the confirm menu item

```
int part = 0;
static String var1 = "";
static String var2 = "";
static String var3 = "";
static String var4 = "";
static String var5 = "";
static String var6 = "";
static String var7 = "";
static String var8 = "";

public void confirm(View view) {
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    if(part == 1) {
        var1 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 2) {
        var2 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 3) {
        var3 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 4) {
        var4 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 5) {
        var5 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 6) {
        var6 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 7) {
        var7 = message2;
    }
    if(part == 8) {
        var8 = message2;
    }
}
```

This is in the main1.xml file (menu folder):

`item android:id="@+id/action_confirm"
        android:title="@string/action_confirm"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        android:onClick="confirm"`

Error:

```
10-23 16:22:40.075: W/dalvikvm(18767): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4176b898)
10-23 16:22:40.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 16:22:40.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18767): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler confirm in class com.test.builder.MainActivity
10-23 16:22:40.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:242)
10-23 16:22:40.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18767):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:443)
```

Comment: It would help to see your stack trace too... 'NullPointerException' etc...

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: Oops - I should've included that: Edited in OP

Comment: Parameter might be wrong. It will not be View. It could be MenuItem

Comment: javascript is still != Java

Comment: (MenuItem Item) instead of (View view) fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @user3431672 says, the method parameter should not be a view but MenuItem. Click [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) to learn more details.